# Why does the display only update on the first square clicked?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, onclicklistener

I am re-building an app in Vue that was originally pure Javascript. The basics are given a field of (3 or 6) squares that are random colors picking the correct color based on the (r,g,b) hint.

I am creating my squares and adding `@click` listeners to them like so:

```
<div class="gameSpace">
    <div
        v-for='(color, ndx) in colors'
        :style='{backgroundColor: color}'
        class="gameSquare"
        @click='checkColor($event, ndx)'>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `checkColor` function is set up like so:

```
checkColor: function(event, ndx) {
    if (event.target.style.backgroundColor === this.goal) {...}
    } else {
        this.message = 'Try Again!';
        this.colors[ndx] = "rgb(52,58,64)";
    }
}
```

When running the game in the browser the first wrong square clicked will change the background color and be "hidden" from the game field. However, every subsequent wrong choice will indeed change the color in the array (verified with several `console.log()`'s) but it will *not* update in the display.

Given that each wrong choice does indeed update the Vue data (again verified with `console.log()`'s) I expect the display to update the color of the squares of all of the wrong choices not just the first.

The behavior is the same regardless of what the first wrong choice is.

Alternatively if there is a better way to get this functionality I'm all ears :D. In that vein I have played with v-show but it causes the squares to move as wrong guesses are hidden.

Comment: Try adding a `key` attribute to each of the divs. This is important for change detection, which might be the problem in your case.
https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#key

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I simply wasn't refreshing or something else happened but I made a small edit to another section of the code and it started working as expected.